# why is my Visual Studio 2019 Pro so slow debugging, after doing Visual Installer update?

Tags: visual-studio

VS2019 was working fine.
Then I ran Visual Installer and added "Mobile development with .NET".
After than, visual Installer "update" button was showing, so I did the update.

But now when I stop my VS2019 project at a breakpoint, single stepping is very slow, taking many seconds per step.
Tried restarting VS2019, and restarting my Windows 10 Pro, but got same slowness.

Opened same project with VS2017, it is debugging is OK, no slowness.

Comment: Very hard to get ahead on questions like these when SO users don't mention the anti-malware product they use.

Comment: My anti-malware product is called Windows 10 64-bit.  However, I recently moved to the 'sticks' and Internet is only 23Mbps down and 4Mbps up.  (sorry, yes I know I should have first ask if you were sitting down).  Does VS2019 hit the Internet a lot?

Comment: I have issues with intellisense being very slow in VS2019. No idea how to solve this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The resolution I found was that the culprit is not Internet, RAM, or CPU.

It is the Disk Usage. Check for your disk usage under the Performance tab in Task Manager. Try and find out which process (Anti-Malware/ anti-virus/ant other process) is eating up your resources.

Kill the culprit and it works smooth. For me, it was Disk Scan Service and Windows Search Service (which is fairly useless).

Check [this link](https://lookeen.com/blog/how-to-disable-windows-search-in-windows-8-and-10) to kill the Windows search service.

Comment: I shut off Cloud-delivered protection and Automatic sample submission (WTF?!)  Why does Microsoft always default to enabling their new, untested "features" WITHOUT telling us users?!  Couple decades ago, Microsoft published a UI guide that stated "never take action without the user's permission" and then they stopped following this.  Also violates the Second Law of Robotics.  :-D

Comment: I had to kill IIS process

Comment: My disk is nvmet ssd, at 6%, cpu around 55%, Mem 73% very slow debugging dotnet core 3.1. VS2019 v.16.8.2

Comment: Please note that Windows search service is linked to many things. It's very lamentable that Outlook is mingled with this. Windows search is a travesty -- nearly useless for searching files AND a resource hog.

Answer (score 5):

Comprehensive deletion of all contents of %TEMP% worked for me - 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/516141/very-hight-cpu-usage-by-visual-studio-2019.html

I can't believe is 2020 and MS can't stop spaffing crap into a temp directory which causes their software to slow to a snails pace with some kind of infinite processing issue. Jeez.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was NVidia NSight for visual studio. Uninstalling it from the windows application list was the only option as it wasn't showing up in the VS2019 Extensions manager.

Comment: +1 I knew my issue was related to recently installing CUDA toolkit 11.1, but I was not even aware I had also installed NSight and that slowed down Visual Studio 2019 to be completely unusable. The bug was fixed in versions after 11.1!

Answer (score 1):

For me it turned out to be a problem with the installation. I had old versions of Visual Studio and .NET libraries still on my machine. I did a full uninstall of Visual Studio, .NET Core SDK, .NET Framework, etc. and then re-installed Visual Studio 2019 and just the .NET libraries that I needed.   After that VS 2019 debugging is speedy.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue stepping over one line of code took me 1400 ms on my VM and 6 ms on my coworker's VM. (Earlier this week he had copied my VM so essentially we were on the same machine).

Took me some time but then I remembered a change I did to my visual studio.

Earlier that week I needed to step into one of our DLLs. To do this I changed my debug settings under Project Properties --> Debug --> Debugger engines. I Checked "Enable native code debugging". This was wonderful to allow me to debug into our DLL and see what was happening on the other side, although it dramatically slowed down my debugging (233x slower to be exact!!!!).

The performance change will different per your solution and how much you are inheriting, but unchecking this did the fix for me!

Answer (score 0):

Delete .vs folder where locate in your project root directory after backup.